# How to disable search in google shortcut in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I assigned a shortcut to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in keymap preferences (select all occurrences, like it is in ***VSCode***). It did not conflict with any of the previous key mappings. However, when I press it, all of the occurrences are selected but also a Safari google search is opened in another window.

How to disable this google search shortcut? Search for google key mapping is not set.

Comment: System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts.

Comment: I'm also having this issue on a Mac in 2019.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000435950-CMD-SHIFT-L-behaviour

> Eugene Morozov:
>   This is a default macOS shortcut, you can disable it at System Settings | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Services| Search with Google. 
>   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180038/strange-behavior-within-ms-word-using-command-shift-l-launches-safari-sometimes

Answer (score 0):

There is already a shortcut for this in IntelliJ - `shift+F6` (may need `Fn` button too). This works across files.

"Search with Google" is a shortcut option found under `Other => Search with Google` (within the Keymap tab in Settings). Is this already assigned to `cmd+shift+L`?

Comment: Search with google shortcut is not set. As I said in my question, there were no conflicts with previous key mappings.